# How to get 2 variables of division and count it php

Tags: php, count, numbers, rule, divide

I am trying to formula rule like :

```
1. adult=2 + child =1/2 is equal to family
2. adult=1 + child =2 is equal to family
```

this is the basic rule,

and if I have :

```
$adult = 7;
$child = 3;

$divider = 2;

$val1 = (float)($adult / $divider);
$set1 = floor($val1);
$remainder1 = ($val1 - (int)$val1)*$divider;

$val2 = (float)($child / $divider);
$set2 = ceil($val2);
$remainder2 = ($val2 - (int)$val2)*$divider;


print $data1 = $set1.':'.$remainder1;
print "<br/>";
print $data2 = $set2.':'.$remainder2;
```

I cant sort out how to split like, from adult=7, child=3, I should get :
2families meaning consists of 2adults +2child and 2 adults + 1child
and the remainder of 3 as and individual.

this is what I am tyring, been trying 2days cant get my head around this, can someone point the way to correctly find the best formula to handle this rule?

UPDATE :

```
7adults 3child needs to be divided :

2adult + 1 or 2child = 1family
```

thats it, expected result would be

```
2 families + 3 individuals, I hope this make things easier!
```

thank you!

Comment: Going by your rules, couldn't there be multiple valid values?

Comment: So let me get this straight. 2 adults and 0.5 children make a family and 1 adult and 2 children make a family. And given a pool of adults and children you need to get the number of families? What is the exact criteria? Do you need to calculate the maximum number of families or the minimum, does one of the rules have precedence over the other?

Comment: @apriede I _think_ OP is saying 2 adults and 1 OR 2 children.

Comment: @JonStirling, well his problem definition is very confusing. He should first try to come up with a solid definition and then figure out an algorithm, which is less to do with programming but with maths and then we can help with the implementation.

Comment: do you not take into account their actual family relationships? perhaps among them four adults, each of which is with a child

Comment: so basicly I have variable spitted out as $adult = 7 and $child =3, then from there I need to divide 2adult + 1child = 1 famlily, 2adult + 2 child = 1family, 1 adult + 2 child = 1 family, so I need it implemented and spit out how many families are there from $adult = 7, $child =3 and how many individuals, it should spit out 2 families + 3individual, that is the formula I wanted to work on, yes its confusing I know, but that is the criteria.

Comment: @Boby, why should it be 2 families and 3 individuals? You probably don't even realize how much of a mess your problem is. As I see it you could have 3(2a +1c) + 1i = 3fam + 1i, (2a + 2c) + (2a +1c) + 3i = 2fam +3i or (2a + 1c) + (1a + 2c) + 4i = 2fam + 4i. As Jon said in the very first post there are multiple answers possible and you have not improved your question to disambiguate it. You are not gonna get help until you improve it because we can't help unless you can say what you need.

Comment: @apriede updated question thank you

Comment: @Boby, I am giving up. You basically did not provide any clarification just one arbitrary case without any context of why it should be like that. You never answered 'Why?'. Try to figure out what you want and then ask a question, because now it seems you don't understand yourself what you want or need.